# Dispatching an action based on condition via ngrx/effects

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I created an effect which register an user, it works but when I tried to register with existing user it dispatched the success action.

Obviously I want to dispatch failure action based on condition that I have on the backend side `success: false or success: true`. Also, will I be able to dispatch the failure action twice via effect ?

Here is the effect:

```js
 @Effect() register$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(fromActions.REGISTER)
        .pipe(
        map((action: fromActions.Register) => action.payload),
        switchMap(user => {
            return this.authService.RegisterUser(user)
        }))
        .pipe(
        map(message => ({ type: fromActions.REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: message })),
        catchError(err => {
            return Observable.of({ type: fromActions.REGISTER_FAILURE, payload: err })
        }));
```

[image: Here is the payload:]

Comment: Your server side should be returning an error status of 409, 400 or similar to indicate there is an error.

Comment: Thank you so much.